# Extract unique rows from two data file

Tags: python, pandas, unique, extract

I have two large excel files and would like to extract rows which are unique in each file.

For example, I have

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [100,50,20,10],
'C1': ['a','b','c','d'],
'C2': ['g','h','i','j'],})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [100,40,20,5],
'C1': ['a','z','c','d'],
'C2': ['g','h','i','m'],})
```

First row and 3rd row are shared between df1 and df2.
(a,g,100  or c,i,20)
Second row and 4th row are not shared between df1 and df2, and I want to extract those rows.
(b,h,50.  d,j,10.  z,h,40, and d,m,5).

If you could tell me how to do this using python, I would be grateful for that very much.

Thank you guys for your feedback.
If I could get below outputs, that should be great.

```
df1only=pd.DataFrame({'Value': [50,10],'C1': ['b','d'],'C2': ['h','j'],})

df2only = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [40,5],'C1': ['z','d'],'C2': ['h','m']})
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: do you want one dataframe or keep the two?

Comment: I've seen this before. One way is to create a mask: `m = ~df1.isin(df2).all(1)` and then access the values as this: `df1[m]` and `df2[m]` or to get it all together `pd.concat([df1,df2]).loc[m]`

Comment: for one dataframe use `pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['Value', 'C1', 'C2'])` else create a mask suggested by @AntonvBR

Answer (score 2):

Using `symmetric_difference` after create the `tuple`

```
set(df1.apply(tuple,1)).symmetric_difference(set(df2.apply(tuple,1)))
Out[653]: {('b', 'h', 50), ('d', 'j', 10), ('d', 'm', 5), ('z', 'h', 40)}
```

Or simply

```
set(df1.apply(tuple,1))^set(df2.apply(tuple,1))
Out[654]: {('b', 'h', 50), ('d', 'j', 10), ('d', 'm', 5), ('z', 'h', 40)}
```

Comment: This is ofc the best way if you just want to get the values out.

Comment: @d_kennetz yet, this has nothing to do with pandas. But as often we need to make assumptions about the desired output. OP might want to keep the dataframe format, in which case, this is not really desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can for instance.

1) Create a mask with non duplicates (~ inverts the selection). Thanks to Wen's comment for this solution your indexes need to be aligned.

```
m = ~df1.isin(df2).all(1)
# Access dataframe with one of below
#df1[m]
#df2[m]
#pd.concat([df1,df2]).loc[m]
```

2) Remove duplicates from a joined dataframe (fail-safe, assuming your values are sets of 3)

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

3) You could as a variant to 2 passa a lambda function to loc.

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).loc[lambda x: ~x.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: Just a kindly reminder , this need index match as well , so it df1 and df2 have different index , this will fail.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Answer (score 1):

This will add a column by what filtering based on where they merge:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
final = merged[merged['_merge'] != 'both']
print(final)
```

This does a right outer merge of df1 and df2 and adds a column indicating where the merge occurred and if the row is unique to the df or is only present in one or the other:

```
>>> merged[merged['_merge'] != 'both']
  C1 C2  Value      _merge
1  b  h     50   left_only
3  d  j     10   left_only
4  z  h     40  right_only
5  d  m      5  right_only
```